# compatibility on changing tcl/tk intepreter from active TCL to tclkit

Tags: tcl

Since active tcl will be charged, I want to change to a free interpreter like tclkit,
what is the main difference between these two interpreters, do I need to modify my source in a large scale or simple just modify some modules.

Comment: Care to provide a link to any resource claiming that prospective change in the distribution policy of ActiveTcl?

Comment: sorry for the unsure statement, http://www.activestate.com/activetcl/license-agreement  My friends told me that, but when dig further, I found the company just limited its redistribution.   Thank you for your advice

Answer (score 2):

Both are Tcl interpreters, and if you have the same version (as reported by `info patchlevel`) then you have the *same* version. **There are very few differences indeed.** Those differences:

- ActiveTcl comes with more third-party packages than Tclkit (though you can use kit-built libraries or build your own packages with both). This is what you'd expect from the kind of full-service Tcl distribution that it is.
- Tclkit tends to come with support for fewer character sets and timezones; you can add these back in if you need them. This is because the Tclkit distribution was designed to be used in much more embedded situations (and, originally, to fit on a floppy disk; that's mostly irrelevant now that nobody has floppies any more).
- There are differences in startup, library locations, etc. Of course.

That said, the commercial tools built on top of the ActiveTcl platform (notably the ActiveState TDK) can actually produce packaged software using what they term basekits, which are effectively tclkits. They use the same packaging technology, the same file format. (The name is different for branding reasons, and they might have slightly different sets of default-packaged goodies.)

---

Myself, I use ActiveTcl *and* Tclkit on the same system. (I also compile my own builds of Tcl direct from source, but then you'd expect that as I'm a developer of Tcl itself.) ActiveTcl is very convenient for when I just want to write code, and Tclkit is nice for when I'm distributing an app to other people in my organization.

Comment: I always test my code using ActiveState Tcl while developing and then warp the entire code in a starkit for distribution (if required). The only thing that didn't work for me are some widget commands for ::ttk::treeview (probably because some package was missing)